# GROUP BY causes ORDER BY not to work

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by, left-join

This is my SQL;

```
SELECT
    cs.name,
    ct.name AS type,
    cr.date,
    cr.hg_version,
    cr.public,
    cr.tag,
    cr.reference,
    cr.description
FROM changelog_systems cs
LEFT JOIN changelog_rows cr ON cr.changelog_system_id = cs.id
LEFT JOIN changelog_types ct ON ct.id = cr.type_id
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY cr.date ASC
```

The problem is that I'm not getting my systems with their latest date; instead it just gets the last row that survives the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Why are you using `GROUP BY` at all since you are not doing any aggregation?

Comment: You should standardise your query (the group by part), I think it would reveal the problematic that is rather unclear here.

Comment: Your usage of `group by` is invalid in SQL and will be rejected by every other DBMS (and MySQL if configured properly). Read this to understand why you get inconsistent results from a "wrong" query: http://rpbouman.blogspot.de/2007/05/debunking-group-by-myths.html and http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/06/wrong-group-by-makes-your-queries-fragile/

Answer (score 1):

Actually your query is wrong altogether. You cannot use non aggregate columns in your SELECT clause. You group by name and all the other columns in your SELECT clause are not grouped by.
MySQL will still accept this (wrong) query if you don't have the option ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY set, but it doesn't make it any less wrong. So what you should do is rewrite the query so it does give you a predictable result. For more info see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode%5Fonly%5Ffull%5Fgroup%5Fby